# Logistic regression - defining reference level in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I am going nuts trying to figure this out. How can I in R, define the reference level to use in a binary logistic regression? What about the multinomial logistic regression? Right now my code is:

```
logistic.train.model3 <- glm(class~ x+y+z,
                         family=binomial(link=logit), data=auth, na.action = na.exclude)
```

my response variable is "YES" and "NO". I want to predict the probability of someone responding with "YES".

I DO NOT want to recode the variable to 0 / 1. Is there a way I can tell the model to predict "YES" ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Make class a factor - see `?factor`

Comment: My class variable, is a factor variable. I am looking to assign the event, or the value of class that the logistic regression predicts. Right now it is predicting "NO", I want it to predict "YES".

Comment: ok use the `I` function (as is): I(class=="yes")

Comment: why would you do that? just multiple the coefficients by -1... Also `relevel(class, ref = 'YES')`

Comment: @user20650 can you please demonstrate where you put that function / insert that line of code? That seems to be the answer/ what I am looking for.

Comment: @rawr I want to not change the variable values. I have tons of code that is reliant on their values, additioanlly, if I have mutlinominal regression this is a pain.

Comment: It would be transparent if you created a new variable, inverse of `class` and use that in the model. Since it will have a new name, all the output will be clear about which variable/reference was used.

Comment: @blast00; You can use it as `glm(I(class=="YES") ~ x+y+z`. Note while this will work for `binomial` if your outcome has more than two levels it will result in comparing one level to the rest. Defining the factor levels pre regression is best the way go here - it is only one line of code

Comment: @rawr; apologies being thick..deleted

Comment: user20650 - thank you here. Case closed. Post the answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Assuming you have class saved as a factor, use the `relevel()` function:

```
auth$class <- relevel(auth$class, ref = "YES")
```

Comment: Note that, when using `auth$class <- relevel(auth$class, ref = "YES")`, you are actually predicting "NO", not "YES".

Comment: if anyone doesn't have class saved as a factor, just do relevel(factor(auth$class), ref="YES")

Answer (score 22):

Note that, when using `auth$class <- relevel(auth$class, ref = "YES")`, you are actually predicting "NO".

**To predict "YES", the reference level must be "NO"**. Therefore, you have to use `auth$class <- relevel(auth$class, ref = "NO")`.

It's a common mistake people do since most the time their oucome variable is a vector of `0` and `1`, and people want to predict `1`.

But when such a vector is considered as a factor variable, the reference level is `0` (see below) so that people effectively predict `1`. Likewise, your reference level must be "NO" so that you will predict "YES".

```
set.seed(1234)
x1 <- sample(c(0, 1), 50, replace = TRUE)
x2 <- factor(x1)
str(x2)
#Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 ...You can see that reference level is 0
```

Comment: this answer really helped me after being so confused - thank you!