# Confused with the reference level in logistic regression in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I am confused with the answer from
[Logistic regression - defining reference level in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23282048/logistic-regression-defining-reference-level-in-r)

It said if you want to predict the probability of "Yes", you set as  `relevel(auth$class, ref = "YES")`. However, in my experiment, if we have a binary response variable with "0" and "1". We only get the estimation for probability of "1" when we set `relevel(factor(y),ref="0")`.

```
n <- 200
x <- rnorm(n)
sumx <- 5 + 3*x
exp1 <- exp(sumx)/(1+exp(sumx))
y <- rbinom(n,1,exp1) #probability here is for 1
model1 <- glm(y~x,family = "binomial")
summary(model1)$coefficients
            Estimate Std. Error  z value     Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) 5.324099  1.0610921 5.017565 5.233039e-07
x           2.767035  0.7206103 3.839849 1.231100e-04
model2 <- glm(relevel(factor(y),ref="0")~x,family = "binomial")
summary(model2)$coefficients
            Estimate Std. Error  z value     Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) 5.324099  1.0610921 5.017565 5.233039e-07
x           2.767035  0.7206103 3.839849 1.231100e-04
```

So what is my mistake? Actually, what is glm() to predict in default if we use response other than "0" and "1"?

Comment: If `P(0)` is the probability of 0, `P(1)` is the probability of 1, then  `P(0) = 1 - P(1)`. Thus, you can always calculate the probability of the reference level, regardless of which level you set as the reference.

Comment: @eipi10, yes, I understand that. I just want to know is there misunderstanding for me to the original answer? I think if we want to get probability of "Yes", we should set relevel(auth$class, ref = "No"), am I correct? And what is reference level here means?

Comment: That's correct. But you could also set the reference level to "Yes" and you could still get the probability of "Yes" by doing 1 - P(No). The reference level just means that the model is predicting the probability of the other (non-reference) level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `P(0)` is the probability of 0 and `P(1)` is the probability of 1, then `P(0) = 1 - P(1)`. Thus, you can always calculate the probability of the reference level, regardless of which level you set as the reference.

For example, `predict(model1, type="response")` gives you the probability of the non-reference level. `1 - predict(model1, type="response")` gives you the probability of the reference level.

You also asked, "what is `glm()` to predict in default if we use response other than '0' and '1'." For (binomial) logistic regression to be appropriate, your outcome needs to be a categorical variable with two categories. You can call them whatever you want, 0/1, black/white, because/otherwise, Mal/Serenity, etc. One will be the reference level--whichever you prefer--and the model will give you the probability of the other level. The probability of the reference level is just 1 minus the probability of the other level.

If your outcome has more than two categories, you can use a [multinomial logistic regression](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/multinomial-logistic-regression/) model, but the principle is similar.